# Changing ListView text color

Tags: android, android-listview

I have `ListView` that shows data:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

The `headlines` is an array:

```
List headlines;
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How to change the text color, style and size? There isn't any `android:textColor` on the `ListView`.

Comment: The ListView will not have text color, the contents of the list will. You can set those attributes where you have defined your list item layouts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find the file `simple_list_item_1.xml` from your sdk installation, copy it to your project's layout folder, rename it and make whatever color/text changes you want in there.  Then replace the layout call in your program with your new layout name (don't forget that since you will be using your own list row layout you need to remove the `android.` from in front of the layout call).

It should look something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.your_row_layout, headlines);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow...Totally in awe of this answer!

Comment: Best answer i have found for the problem So Far . .

Comment: The remove android really saved me a few additional hours.